# Querying remote data stores from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an ASP.NET application that suppose to connect to many different data stores and query them for data. Each data store contains different data: it can be an SQL DB, an XML file, or anything that can store data. The result is always an XML.

The remote data stores expose a WCF service (which I will also implement) that will allow me to query the data store and return the results.

My question is: how exactly should I implement the querying mechanism? Should I define my own query language? should I use an existing solution?

Thank you,

Katie

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your requirements, but you might want to look into WCF Data Services. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it can do what you need. It's just something I've come across, I don't have any experience with it. I just read it can handle multiple types of data sources (including non-relational), which I thought might make it interesting for you. 
The way I understand it, Data Services make it easy to expose your data source as a RESTful web service in a unified manner, which you should then easily be able to transform into XML using the .NET client library ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772%28VS.100%29.aspx ).